# Way around auto renaming DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas when you define a dataframe and merge it to other dataframes on and on, the column names will be replaced with either a the `exact name or _x or _y` etc depending on how many you merged. This becomes a pain when you find that you had to implement something in your earlier code and you go back to change and merge a an extra dataframe. Now this then renames the `exact name or _x or _y` and now you have to replace the columns that come afterwards with the newly created names.

Is there a way around this? Do i need to use a table type of data-structure like hdf5 etc?

Comment: A possible solution is to not have duplicate column names to start with, or to rename such columns before merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe help set parameter `suffixes` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({'k': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'], 'v': [1, 2, 3]})
print left
    k  v
0  K0  1
1  K1  2
2  K2  3

right = pd.DataFrame({'k': ['K0', 'K0', 'K3'], 'v': [4, 5, 6]})
print right
    k  v
0  K0  4
1  K0  5
2  K3  6

result = pd.merge(left, right, on='k', suffixes=['', '_r'])
print result
    k  v  v_r
0  K0  1    4
1  K0  1    5
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael @joris, this will work. Better yet, is there a way to add these suffixes to the main dataframe, even if its on the import stage of a file to a dataframe. E.g having `column1_x, column2_x, column3_x` etc. This would be better than renaming all the columns yourself

Comment: Hard question. I think no. Only if header have same names, you can use parameter `prefix ` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).